# How to implement Lambda expression in Apex

Tags: apex, interface

I have this below interface in Java

```
public interface DoubleOperator {

    double applyAsDouble(double left, double right);
}
```

And below implementing it using Lambda  -

```
DoubleOperator [] ops = {
(a, b) -> a + b,
(a, b) -> a - b
};
```

How we can implement this in Apex . Any suggestions. Like using Inferface in Apex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambdas don't exist in Apex. You can use interfaces, but you still have to write out the entire class:

```
 public interface DoubleOperator {
   double applyAsDouble(double left, double right);
 }
 public class AddDoubleOperator implements DoubleOperator {
   double applyAsDouble(double left, double right) {
     return left + right;
   }
 }
 public class SubtractDoubleOperator implements DoubleOperator {
   double applyAsDouble(double left, double right) {
     return left - right;
   }
 }
 DoubleOperator[] ops = new DoubleOperator[] {
   new AddDoubleOperator(), new SubtractDoubleOperator()
 };
```

While it'd be nice to have lambdas, that's just not something we can do today in Apex.

Comment: Worth also saying Apex doesn't even support anonymous implementations.